# How to extract hyperlink using php

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I have searched online and thought this would work but it doesn't for some reason. I'm trying to extract a hyperlink that only displays it's URL from a HTML. I'm only trying to extract the URL within the **td align="center"**. Here is a sample of the HTML doc I'm trying to extract:

```
<td>
    Aug 17
</td>

<td>
    FT
</td>

<td align="right">
    <a href="site1">Arsenal ruby</a>
</td>

**<td align="center">**
    <a href="site2">1-3</a>
</td>

<td><a href="site3">Aston Villa</a></td>


<td style="text-align:right;">60,003</td>
```

And here is my PHP code to extract it from the td align="center":

```
<?php

//$searchURL = "site";
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$site = 'website';
$html = file_get_html($site);

$tabledata = array();

// Find all TD tags with "align=center"
foreach($html->find('td[align=center]') as $e)
echo $e->href . '<br>';

?>
```

I know the code works because the code can extract everything if it is just the td within the barracks.

Comment: Have you tried regular expressions? See [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match)

Comment: You want `td[align=center] a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have identified the `<td>` elements themselves, but you did not go down to the next nesting level to grab the `href` from the `<a>` elements.  You might do that like this:

```
foreach($html->find('td[align=center]') as $e)
echo $e->children(0)->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: This help a lot. Where can I find a good documentation that explains this?

Comment: @Nic - Here, http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm and here, http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm

Comment: Thanks. one more thing It works great but receiving an error message "Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\tutorials\table_new.php on line 20". This is on the echo $e->children(0)->href . '<br>'; that you added, do you know why?

Comment: That's because it just reads the href of the first child node in the td, here is no validation that the td has a node or that this node has a href attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Use the DOM and Xpath:

Select all td elements in the document

`//td`

Only if the align attribute equals "center"

`//td[@align="center"]`

Get the a sub elements

`//td[@align="center"]//a`

Get the href attribute nodes of that `a` elements

`//td[@align="center"]//a/@href`

Source example:

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<td>
    FT
</td>
<td align="right">
    <a href="site1">Arsenal ruby</a>
</td>
**<td align="center">**
    <a href="site2">1-3</a>
</td>
<td><a href="site3">Aston Villa</a></td>
<td style="text-align:right;">60,003</td>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//td[@align="center"]//a/@href');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  var_dump($node->value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You selected the td element. The anchor element is the child of the td element.

```
// Find all TD tags with "align=center"
foreach($html->find('td[align=center]') as $e)
echo $e->firstChild()->getAttribute('href') . '<br>';
```